# How to count characters, letters, spaces from user input

Tags: java, string, char, counter

I am having trouble to convert user input string into character array. whenever i convert the string into char array it only display the first word.  When i initialize String with some text this code run successfully but i use scanner to take input this code does't work. Basically i want to count letters, characters, spaces and other from user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String s=scan.next();
 count(s);

 }
 public static void count(String x)
{
int letter=0,digit=0,spaces=0,other=0;
char[] c=x.toCharArray();

for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
{
  if(Character.isLetter(c[i]))
  {
   letter ++;
  }
  else if(Character.isDigit(c[i]))
  {
    digit ++;
  }
  else if(Character.isSpaceChar(c[i]))
  {
    spaces ++;
  }
  else
  {
    other ++;
  }
 }
 System.out.println(" the total letter is "+ letter);
 System.out.println(" the total digits is "+ digit);
 System.out.println(" the total spaces is "+ spaces);
 System.out.println("other is "+ other);
}

}
```

Comment: `String s=scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is finding the count of letters and digits and etc., you don't have to convert the string to an array of characters. You only need cast each char of your input string to character while looping through the input string. In the following I am going to rewrite your **count** function:

```
 public static void count(String x)
 {
    int letter=0,digit=0,spaces=0,other=0;

    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
    {
      if(Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)))
      {
         letter ++;
      }
      else if(Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i)))
      {
        digit ++;
      }
      else if(Character.isSpaceChar(c[i]))
      {
        spaces ++;
      }
      else
      {
        other ++;
      }
    } 
    System.out.println(" the total letter is "+ letter);
    System.out.println(" the total digits is "+ digit);
    System.out.println(" the total spaces is "+ spaces);
    System.out.println("other is "+ other);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class tokenizes the user input - so with `scanner.next()` you will only get the text to the first blank. Try `System.console().readLine()` instead:

```
String s = System.console().readLine()
count(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use String s = scan.nextLine(); not String s=scan.next();